# File Store in a remote server using php

Tags: php, file-upload, remote-server, file-writing

I have done a project in php for a call center .
My goal is to write the call recording files in a remote server. How it possible ?.

My code is ,

```
if(isset($row['recAudioFile'])){
    $path="http://xxxxx.com/testrecordings/";
    $RecordedFile="test.mp3";
    file_put_contents($path.$RecordedFile,base64_decode($row['recAudioFile']));
}
```

> Note : I can't run any php code in the remote server Or establish a FTP Connection.

Comment: You can't use file_put_contents for remote files. You'll need FTP library to save there.

Comment: @D. Dimitrov : Thanks for the replay. Is any other options ???

Comment: google: remote file uploading using php

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776859/php-upload-image-to-remote-server-with-curl

Comment: You need some sort of upload handling on the remote server, be it PHP, Python, Ruby etc. Without that everybody could just place files on remote servers

Comment: @hardiksolanki "_I can't run any php code in the remote server_"

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A Then you must have to upload file through FTP connection. Because there is no other way to do it.

Comment: @hardiksolanki "_... Or establish a FTP Connection._" ;)

Comment: There is no way for you to upload files to a webserver without going server-side scripting. If you could, then that would be a massive security hole.

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A Yes, You need o establish FTP connection through code and upload file on remote server. Check this link : https://shellcreeper.com/move-files-server-to-server-using-simple-php/

Comment: @hardiksolanki Not sure if you read the question, especially the "Note": OP _can't_ establish a FTP connection! "_Because there is no other way to do it._" What about `scp`?

Comment: @kerbholz Sorry my bed!! Yes, OP upload file through scp as well but still need scp detail as well to upload file through scp.

Comment: @hardiksolanki : I need to modify the remote server to use the scp ???