# php cURL post data to remote server not working

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to send data via cURL post but I've never tried it before and I don't know if I'm doing it right.

What I want to do is sent a file via post to a file from my remote server and there read the file and insert data into database but unfortunately it's not working and error_log doesn't show me anything.

My code looks like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://".$host."/file.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            'file' => '@'.realpath(../path/to/file/'.$_POST['file_name'].'.txt'),
            'action' => 'first',
            'check' => $_POST['file_name'],
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

This code is placed after some sql querys and code made to write this sql results into the file that I'm trying to send.

Comment: What do your receive from the server? Just print the `$result` variable. Also, you can read the HTTP status code `$responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);` before you close the connection. Or try without uploading the file

Comment: An issue occurs because CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is supposed to be http_build_query($array), not an array.
http://php.net/manual/ro/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: @Ruben it's the first time I'm using cURL and I don't understand how it really works. What my code is doing is putting that information via post in the CURLOPT_URL, right? Or is it getting that information via post from that url? Cause I'm understanding it like the first case.

Comment: Is there a missing quote in `.realpath(../path/to/file/'.$_POST['file_name'].'.txt')` - should there be one before `../path`

Comment: @NigelRen you're right. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Cat I didn't know that. Thanks for the info! I'll try it later.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the Answer by Shakir Khan you Should follow:
[PHP: upload file from one server to another server - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35569854/7033983)

OR you should read PHP Documentation carefully there is a huge amount of CONSTANT availabe to use: [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like that's the right way to solve my problem. I'll try it later!