# best way to upload file on a distant server

Tags: php, file, upload

I need to upload files from a `[SERVER A]` to a `[SERVER B]`
*(same server, but different environment / subdomain)*

I try to find the best way to do it :

1) Upload my file on `[SERVER A]` then putting it on `[SERVER B]` using FTP protocol ?

2) Executing the upload script on `[SERVER B]` directly ?
( *but for this one, i have no idea how to do it* )

3) Maybe another solution ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you made any attempt?

Comment: How distant we talking here?  Prolly need a really long Cat4 cable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311051/php-upload-file-from-one-server-to-another-server Check this out.

Comment: I didn't tried anything at the moment, i'm trying to find the best solution to apply before coding it.

Comment: Thank you for the link @SmitRaval, i'll check it.

Comment: Sure let me know if it works for you? @MarcPfeiler

Comment: There is no "best" solution. Only you can decide what works for you and what doesn't.

Comment: Asking for “the best way to do X” without specifying _any_ criteria for what would make one better than the other, is rather nonsense to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

**fopen and fwrite**

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0); //Unlimited max execution time

$path = 'newfile.zip';
$url = 'http://example.com/oldfile.zip';
$newfname = $path;
echo 'Starting Download!<br>';
$file = fopen ($url, "rb");
if($file) {
    $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");
    if($newf)
        while(!feof($file)) {
            fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
            echo '1 MB File Chunk Written!<br>';
        }
}
if($file) {
    fclose($file);
}
if($newf) {
    fclose($newf);
}
echo 'Finished!';
?>
```

**FTP**

```
<?php
/**
 * Transfer (Export) Files Server to Server using PHP FTP
 * @link https://shellcreeper.com/?p=1249
 */

/* Remote File Name and Path */
$remote_file = 'files.zip';

/* FTP Account (Remote Server) */
$ftp_host = 'your-ftp-host.com'; /* host */
$ftp_user_name = 'ftp-username@your-ftp-host.com'; /* username */
$ftp_user_pass = 'ftppassword'; /* password */


/* File and path to send to remote FTP server */
$local_file = 'files.zip';

/* Connect using basic FTP */
$connect_it = ftp_connect( $ftp_host );

/* Login to FTP */
$login_result = ftp_login( $connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );

/* Send $local_file to FTP */
if ( ftp_put( $connect_it, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
    echo "WOOT! Successfully transfer $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "Doh! There was a problem\n";
}

/* Close the connection */
ftp_close( $connect_it );
?>
```