# File Upload and Save on another Server PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I currently collect and upload an image using a form on one server (server A), I would like to store it on another server (server B). From the examples I have seen, I would need to save the file and then copy it over using either copy or curl.

I would like to get the file that I receive on server A and send it to server B without actually saving the file on server A. Is there a way for me to do this?
I tried converting the file to a dataURI string and sending it this way, however I think the string is too long and I am getting errors with this.
Thank you in advance for your help!

***UPDATE***
I found my solution lovers!
The file is stored in temporary storage when uploaded. 
You can't use just the filename to save the file on a different server, but you can use the information to create a CurlFile, which can then be passed to your page on the other server to be created (See Shivani Patel's response to [PHP: upload file from one server to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311051/php-upload-file-from-one-server-to-another-server)). This combined with information from http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/ and I got my code working.

Please mark as duplicate if appropriate. I didn't think to look into the temp filename until suggested :)

Comment: then no need to think about server A , just directly upload it server B ...  :) ... make sure your B server have to accept the upload.

Comment: The file is likely already being stored in a temporary location. Most PHP file manipulation functions can accept a file directly, not just a file path. You might want to check here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: @seanvalencourt  -- Thank you your comment! really helped push me in the right direction. If you want to add as an answer I will accept :)

Comment: @MinarMnr - I was expecting someone to say as much! Still need Server A to process the rest of the form. I am sending the file over to Server B to check and store, but wasn't sure how to send a file without saving it first. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `ftp_put()` function as follows

```
// information of second server
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";
// name file in serverA that you want to store file in serverB
$file = 'somefile.png';
$remote_file = 'serverB_file.png';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}
```

I have also gone same thing.. first i moveuploaded file in serverA and then transfer in serverB,,, after complete transfer unlink the file in serverA.

Comment: let me know whether matches your problem or not. If you find it's helpful please accept as correct answer

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond @Veshraj Joshi. I really appreciate it. I think this way, I would still have to save the file - which I wanted to avoid. It is a fantastic answer, not something I would have thought of. Thanks again!