# How to change the path where I store my files

Tags: php, upload, filepath

Currently I am saving PDF files in a folder located at the root of my project in PHP but in this case I need to change this location to a folder located on another server which is different from the one I am running my project on.

The way in which I am assigning the current path to store the files is as follows:

```
if($res['pdf']) {
          $file = $_FILES["pdfToUpload"]["name"];
          $path ="PDF/";

          if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdfToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $path . $file)) {
             
              $res['pdf'] = false;
          }          
      }
```

In the variable I `path` just store the location which is a folder found in the root of my project.

The path that I want to access on the other server to store the files is the following:

```
/SRVNAME/E:/newfolder/project/PDF/
```

I clarify that in the previous path I have to access a different unit that is the one `E:` and this path I tried adding the name of the server but it did not work.

Try assigning the same location to the variable `path` but the file is not stored.

I don't really know if files can be stored in a different location than the project is.

Comment: Other server - meaning another harddrive connected to your computer?

Comment: To a another hard disk than the normal one, which is C: in my case it is drive E: and to a another server from where I have the project running

Comment: One common solution is to save the file locally, and then move or copy it over to the remote machine. How you actually move it depends on your setup. You can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php, FTP, CURL, ..., but you haven't given us enough information about what "another server" really means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The share name (file path) won't look like that. If its a Windows server it's a [UNC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/62e862f4-2a51-452e-8eeb-dc4ff5ee33cc) and it'd look more like this `//SRVNAME/newfolder/project/PDF/`.

Also, the user that the web server is running as will need appropriate permissions to the directory/share.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this, but it seems like `realpath("/SRVNAME/E:/newfolder/project/PDF/");` would give you the absolute system path to the folder.

Answer (score -1):

From What I understood, You have two different servers one running the application and the other is storing the files. To do so, You need to have a file uploading script in the server where the file needs to be uploaded. From the application server, you write a script using PHP CURL to send the file.

For your reference, I'm posting the CURL operations you need to perform in your application script.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, SECOND_SERVER_PATH);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

For more information, you can refer to Shivani's Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311051/php-upload-file-from-one-server-to-another-server)